# Regular Expression for a minus symbol in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, regex

If I have the following regular expression in objective-c:

```
NSString * strippedNumber = [incomingString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"[^0-9.]"
                                                                      withString:@""
                                                                         options:NSRegularExpressionSearch
                                                                           range:NSMakeRange(0, [incomingString length])];
```

How do I add to it to also extract only the minus (-) symbol?  I'm using it already to demonstrate the range 0 to 9.

Thanks

Mike

Comment: From what I can gather, you probably don't need a regex here.

Comment: Another possibility is that you want `@"[^0-9.-]"` instead of `@"[^0-9.]"`.

Comment: `@"[^0-9.]|-"` means your pattern or minus

Comment: Thanks - what would you suggest I do if not use a reg ex? I just want to extract numbers only from the incoming string.

Comment: If you can answer it I can mark it as a solution.  Thanks  Mike.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is to include the `-` as the first, or if negated the second, character of the set expression - in that position it is not taken as special. So:

```
@"[-0-9.]"
```

matches digits, `-` & `.`, and:

```
@"[^-0-9.]"
```

matches anything other than digits, `-` & `.`.

However it appears you are attempting to parse a number, and if you are doing that it is better to match the acceptable format rather than simply to try to delete characters that shouldn't be in a number. For example, with the string:

```
@"asda -123.45 tesco 1.2-3 sainsburys"
```

your approach produces:

```
@"-123.451.2-3"
```

which is probably not what you want.

The exact regular expression you need to match a number depends on what format(s) you are accepting. For example, a number might be:

1. An optional sign: `-?`, a `-` zero or once (`?`)
2. One or more digits: `[0-9]+`
3. An optional fraction part: `(...)?` - whatever `...` is zero or once
4. A fraction part is a decimal point: `\\.`, dot is special so it must be escaped in the regular expression (`\`) and backslash is special in a string so it too must be escaped (`\`)
5. And one or more digits: `[0-9]+`

Put that together and you get `@"-?[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?"` to match a number. To find all the numbers matching this pattern in your string:

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSRegularExpression *re = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"-?[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?" options:0 error:&error];
NSArray *matches = [re matchesInString:incomingString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, incomingString.length)];
for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches)
{
    NSLog(@"match: %@", [incomingString substringWithRange:match.range]);
}
```

running that on the string `@"asda -123.45 tesco 1.2-3 sainsburys"` produces:

```
match: -123.45
match: 1.2
match: -3
```

You might also wish to consider other ways to parse strings, such as `NSScanner`.

HTH